# Errno 28 No space availble on '/var/tmp/...'

Tags: linux, installation, partition, diskspace, disk-partitioning

I would like to install algobox for my studies but it is impossible for me to install it or even to update my computer. I looked for it and I saw that it was probably a problem of space in my partition.

I made the command "df -h" to see what was in my score and it displayed this:

```
Sys. de fichiers Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
devtmpfs           7,8G       0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs              7,8G     15M  7,8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs              7,8G    2,1M  7,8G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p7      69G     66G     0 100% /
tmpfs              7,8G     40K  7,8G   1% /tmp
/dev/loop2         224M    224M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/code/108
/dev/loop0         999M    999M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/android-studio/123
/dev/loop1         143M    143M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/chromium/2105
/dev/loop4         115M    115M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/13741
/dev/nvme0n1p4     976M    247M  663M  28% /boot
/dev/loop5          63M     63M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/deezer-unofficial-player/11
/dev/nvme0n1p2      96M     46M   51M  48% /boot/efi
/dev/nvme0n1p8     114G     40G   69G  37% /home
/dev/loop7          56M     56M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/2566
/dev/loop8          64M     64M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core20/1623
/dev/loop10        347M    347M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
/dev/loop11        176M    176M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/postman/133
/dev/loop17        151M    151M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/remmina/5379
/dev/loop18         82M     82M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/discord/143
/dev/loop19        165M    165M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
/dev/loop21         48M     48M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/16778
/dev/loop22         92M     92M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop23         71M     71M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core22/275
/dev/loop24        128K    128K     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/bare/5
/dev/loop27        219M    219M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
/dev/loop28        415M    415M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-42-2204/29
tmpfs              1,6G     88K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: According to your list of file systems, `/var/tmp` is in your root file system (`/`), and this seems to be full.

Comment: Can you try removing unused softwares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The /var/tmp does not seem to be mounted separate from / and it looks you still have 3G free

```
Sys. de fichiers Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
/dev/nvme0n1p7      69G     66G     0 100% /
```

I would suggest running a "df -i" to see the inode utilization at the IUse% column(it must be under 100%) as if you have a lot of small files, each one will utilize one inode and if you are using 100% of inodes you will get the "No space left error".